# Service Fabric with F# not working

Tags: c#, f#, azure-service-fabric

I tried to convert the default template for "Service Fabric Applicatoin" with "Actor Service" from C# to F#.

Here is the github [repo](https://github.com/tenigma/FSharpSFActorApp).

I can compile everything but when I deploy it to the local cluster I get `System.ArgumentNullException`. Does anyoune know what is wrong here?

Here is the stack trace (it's in german, sorry):

```
bei System.Reflection.Emit.FieldBuilder..ctor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, String fieldName, Type type, Type[] requiredCustomModifiers, Type[] optionalCustomModifiers, FieldAttributes attributes)
bei System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineFieldNoLock(String fieldName, Type type, Type[] requiredCustomModifiers, Type[] optionalCustomModifiers, FieldAttributes attributes)
bei System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineField(String fieldName, Type type, Type[] requiredCustomModifiers, Type[] optionalCustomModifiers, FieldAttributes attributes)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodBodyTypesBuilder.BuildRequestBodyType(ICodeBuilderNames codeBuilderNames, CodeBuilderContext context, MethodDescription methodDescription)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodBodyTypesBuilder.Build(ICodeBuilderNames codeBuilderNames, CodeBuilderContext context, MethodDescription methodDescription)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodBodyTypesBuilder.Build(InterfaceDescription interfaceDescription)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.CodeBuilder.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ICodeBuilder.GetOrBuildMethodBodyTypes(Type interfaceType)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodDispatcherBuilder`1.Build(InterfaceDescription interfaceDescription)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.CodeBuilder.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ICodeBuilder.GetOrBuilderMethodDispatcher(Type interfaceType)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Remoting.Builder.ActorCodeBuilder.GetOrCreateMethodDispatcher(Type actorInterfaceType)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Remoting.Runtime.ActorMethodDispatcherMap..ctor(ActorTypeInformation actorTypeInformation)
bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorRuntime.<RegisterActorAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
---  Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
bei Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\Users\tomas\Projects\playground\MyServiceFabricApp\MyActor\Program.fs:Zeile 18.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is very subtle. I stumbled across this myself.

Each parameter in the actor interface must have an **explicit** name. Thanks to Isaac Abraham who mentioned this in his [blog post](https://cockneycoder.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/building-azure-service-fabric-actors-with-f-part-1/) (But this post is very outdated)

Change your actor interface from this:

```
type IMyActor =
  inherit IActor
  abstract member GetCountAsync : unit -> Task<int>
  abstract member SetCountAsync : int -> Task
```

To the following: (notice the count argument)

```
type IMyActor =
  inherit IActor
  abstract member GetCountAsync : unit -> Task<int>
  abstract member SetCountAsync : count: int -> Task
```

After this change your example worked fine for me.